# What would be the best approach patch-finding the pointer of a certain function on the XNU Kernel?

Tags: ios, c, reverse-engineering, jailbreak

I am currently working on an iOS Jailbreak for iOS 13.7.
As part of the jailbreak, I need to do a series of patches to the XNU Kernel live in the memory.
Of course, the kernel is protected by `kASLR`, `KPP` / `KTRR`, and other memory watchdogs that would trigger a Kernel Panic if something is modified.
As luck would have it, `KTRR` (Kernel Text Ready Only Region) can only protect, well, static data that is not supposed to change (i.e. the `TEXT` section and constants). The variables can still be altered.

I am building a PatchFinder which is supposed to locate a function or a variable in the XNU memory based on tell-tale symbols and I am wondering what would be the most effective approach for this.

I am currently adapting on top of the PatchFinder [made publicly available](https://github.com/in7egral/taig8-ios-jailbreak-patchfinder/blob/master/patchfinder.c) back in the iOS 8 era by `in7egal` which looks like this:

```
uint32_t find_cs_enforcement_disable_amfi(uint32_t region, uint8_t* kdata, size_t ksize)
{
    // Find a function referencing cs_enforcement_disable_amfi
    const uint8_t search_function[] = {0x20, 0x68, 0x40, 0xF4, 0x40, 0x70, 0x20, 0x60, 0x00, 0x20, 0x90, 0xBD};
    uint8_t* ptr = memmem(kdata, ksize, search_function, sizeof(search_function));
    if(!ptr)
        return 0;

    // Only LDRB in there should try to dereference cs_enforcement_disable_amfi
    uint16_t* ldrb = find_last_insn_matching(region, kdata, ksize, (uint16_t*) ptr, insn_is_ldrb_imm);
    if(!ldrb)
        return 0;

    // Weird, not the right one.
    if(insn_ldrb_imm_imm(ldrb) != 0 || insn_ldrb_imm_rt(ldrb) > 12)
        return 0;

    // See what address that LDRB is dereferencing
    return find_pc_rel_value(region, kdata, ksize, ldrb, insn_ldrb_imm_rn(ldrb));
}
```

I wonder if there is any faster way or a more reliable way to locate the `cs_enforcement_disable_amfi`.

Once found by the PatchFinder in the XNU Kernel memory, it's used like this:

```
uint32_t cs_enforcement_disable_amfi = find_cs_enforcement_disable_amfi(kernel_base, kdata, ksize);
    printf("cs_enforcement_disable_amfi is at=0x%08x\n",cs_enforcement_disable_amfi);
    if (cs_enforcement_disable_amfi){
        char patch[] ="\x00\xbf\x00\xbf\x00\xbf\x00\xbf\x00\xbf";
        kern_return_t kernret = vm_write(proccessTask, cs_enforcement_disable_amfi+kernel_base, patch, sizeof(patch)-1);
        if (kernret == KERN_SUCCESS){
            printf("Successfully patched cs_enforcement_disable_amfi\n");
        }
    }
```

So the PatchFinder has to be able to reliably return the pointer to `cs_enforcement_disable_amfi` otherwise I am blindly writing to an invalid (or valid but different) address which almost certainly will trigger memory corruption.

The current code does return a valid pointer to `cs_enforcement_disable_amfi` most of the time, but randomly panics the kernel about 10-15% of the time which means the address it returns 10-15% of the time is invalid. Not sure how to make it more reliable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable you're looking for doesn't exist anymore.

The bytes in your first snippet make up Thumb instructions, which find this function in AMFI in a 32bit kernelcache:

```
0x8074ad04      90b5           push {r4, r7, lr}
0x8074ad06      01af           add r7, sp, 4
0x8074ad08      0d48           ldr r0, [0x8074ad40]
0x8074ad0a      7844           add r0, pc
0x8074ad0c      0078           ldrb r0, [r0]
0x8074ad0e      0128           cmp r0, 1
0x8074ad10      03d1           bne 0x8074ad1a
0x8074ad12      0020           movs r0, 0
0x8074ad14      00f04efa       bl 0x8074b1b4
0x8074ad18      30b9           cbnz r0, 0x8074ad28
0x8074ad1a      7c69           ldr r4, [r7, 0x14]
0x8074ad1c      002c           cmp r4, 0
0x8074ad1e      05d0           beq 0x8074ad2c
0x8074ad20      2068           ldr r0, [r4]
0x8074ad22      40f44070       orr r0, r0, 0x300
0x8074ad26      2060           str r0, [r4]
0x8074ad28      0020           movs r0, 0
0x8074ad2a      90bd           pop {r4, r7, pc}
```

Given the magic constant `0x300` and the fact that AMFI's `__TEXT_EXEC` segment is quite small, we can easily find this in other kernels, including 64bit ones.
This is what it looks like on an iPhone 5s on 8.4:

```
0xffffff800268d2e4      f44fbea9       stp x20, x19, [sp, -0x20]!
0xffffff800268d2e8      fd7b01a9       stp x29, x30, [sp, 0x10]
0xffffff800268d2ec      fd430091       add x29, sp, 0x10
0xffffff800268d2f0      f30307aa       mov x19, x7
0xffffff800268d2f4      e8fc1110       adr x8, section.com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity.10.__DATA.__bss
0xffffff800268d2f8      1f2003d5       nop
0xffffff800268d2fc      08054039       ldrb w8, [x8, 1]
0xffffff800268d300      a8000037       tbnz w8, 0, 0xffffff800268d314
0xffffff800268d304      130100b4       cbz x19, 0xffffff800268d324
0xffffff800268d308      680240b9       ldr w8, [x19]
0xffffff800268d30c      08051832       orr w8, w8, 0x300
0xffffff800268d310      680200b9       str w8, [x19]
0xffffff800268d314      00008052       mov w0, 0
0xffffff800268d318      fd7b41a9       ldp x29, x30, [sp, 0x10]
0xffffff800268d31c      f44fc2a8       ldp x20, x19, [sp], 0x20
0xffffff800268d320      c0035fd6       ret
```

But by the time of iOS 11, the variable is gone:

```
0xfffffff006245d84      f44fbea9       stp x20, x19, [sp, -0x20]!
0xfffffff006245d88      fd7b01a9       stp x29, x30, [sp, 0x10]
0xfffffff006245d8c      fd430091       add x29, sp, 0x10
0xfffffff006245d90      f30307aa       mov x19, x7
0xfffffff006245d94      130100b4       cbz x19, 0xfffffff006245db4
0xfffffff006245d98      680240b9       ldr w8, [x19]
0xfffffff006245d9c      08051832       orr w8, w8, 0x300
0xfffffff006245da0      680200b9       str w8, [x19]
0xfffffff006245da4      00008052       mov w0, 0
0xfffffff006245da8      fd7b41a9       ldp x29, x30, [sp, 0x10]
0xfffffff006245dac      f44fc2a8       ldp x20, x19, [sp], 0x20
0xfffffff006245db0      c0035fd6       ret
```

Looking at iOS 12.0b1, we can learn the signature of that function:

```
_vnode_check_exec(ucred*, vnode*, vnode*, label*, label*, label*, componentname*, unsigned int*, void*, unsigned long)
```

So yeah, finding this function is really easy:

1. Find AMFI's `__TEXT_EXEC` segment.
2. Find an `orr wN, wN, 0x300` in it.

But that won't help you unless you defeat kernel integrity.